TEM Waves in conductors
I am having some trouble understanding ohmic losses in conductors. Suppose I have copper cable and run some high frequency sinusoidal current throught it. The skin effect should be very noticable and the TEM wave should not propagate deeply into the conductor. Why do losses increase as the TEM wave penetrates the conductor less and less? If the wave does not penetrate the conductor at all (its entirely in free space), shouldnt it have zero damping?

because the Ohmic loss goes $I^2R$ or $j^2/\sigma$, that is for a given conductor, fixed $\sigma$, the loss is proportional to the square of the current density. Note this dependence is independent of the particular propagating mode, be it TEM, TE, LSE, or whatever.

Oh yes, now I see! It was that simple lol

Just to be clear, the TEM wave is in the air or dielectric surrounding the conductor, not in the conductor (as your title implies). If this is not what you had in mind, could you add a diagram showing the relationship between the wave, the conductor, and the current that you are asking about?
